# 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found. in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, html, css, http-status-code-404

I need some help here.
The first page works just fine but other pages wont work at all when I click on them.
let me show you my code.
And even though I added .htacces but I cant open the website without index.php in URL
HELP!
I hope there is a solution cuz I searched a lot
Controller:

```
    <?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
      }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('pages/intro');
    }

   public function Getincontact()
    {
        $this->load->view('pages/getincontact');
    }
    public function EDUCATION()
    {
        $this->load->view('pages/EDUCATION');
        
    }
    public function INTERNSHIP()
    {
        $this->load->view('pages/INTERNSHIP');
        
    }
    public function CERTIFICATES()
    {
        $this->load->view('pages/CERTIFICATES');
        
    }
    public function PROJECTSANDACHIEVEMENTS()
    {
        $this->load->view('pages/PROJECTSANDACHIEVEMENTS');
        
    }
}
```

intro page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ASAYLALAMAWI ^ CV</title>

</head>
<body>
    <?php
            $this->load->view('styles/introstyle');
    ?>

<input type="radio" name="toggle" id="radio1">
  <div class="fillers">
    <h2>CV</h2>
    <h1>ASAYL ALAMAWI</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="radio1" class="ham-menu">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
       </label>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="overlay">
  <input type="radio" name="toggle" id="radio2">
<label for="radio2" class="cross">X</label>
    <nav>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/getincontact">GET IN CONTACT</a>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/EDUCATION">EDUCATION</a>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/INTERNSHIP">INTERNSHIP</a>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/CERTIFICATES">CERTIFICATES</a>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/PROJECTSANDACHIEVEMENTS">PROJECTS AND ACHIEVEMENTS</a>
    </nav>
  </div>

  

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the
.htaccsess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```